# IOS - Is is required to implement ATT into app before publishing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, privacy

I am about to submit my app to App Store, but just wondered if it is required to implement the ATT alert into apps to publish in App Store. I looked into it and found that Apple postponed that until early next year. So to make sure, I called the Apple Developer Support, a guy said that it's required. I am confused not. Again, is it required to implement the APP alert at this point?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to implement  ATT into your app otherwise your app will be rejected by Apple.

We are talking about this guy :

[image: App Tracking Transparency]

---

If you interest this links are useful for this topic as well:

[article about Apple policy for tracking change](https://techcrunch.com/2020/12/08/apple-takes-aim-at-adtech-hysteria-over-ios-app-tracking-change/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAJ5HShYVsXFlY8cokuR_DeLTO85s07RptUWrec--QcxZegF7POteWs4QhSuz_xEQgrJxkUqHoprJYGAylt5lHVDZFVn0PxN0of5z-oubZBnReQxzMa2l0lStDbVBxw_L1ctFk5ptRZxx9t3afO9pYWg-fwQPpTAyuBqQIgQE-AIw)

[apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency/attrackingmanager/3547037-requesttrackingauthorizationwith?language=objc)

Comment: @HahaHoHo you are welcome! you can accept this answer by clicking the tick if you wish.

Comment: sorry. I really did :)

Comment: is it possible to customize the button ordering here?